# How to use yield put inside yield all

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I want to make n number of api call and i am doing as floows

```
   try {
    ....
     yield all(
          action.uploadDocsBody.map(u =>
            call(uploadDocs, {
              ...,

            }),
          ),
        );

     yield put({
      type: UPLOADDOCS_COMPLETED,
      payload: { statusText: 'Success' },
    });

 } catch (e) {

    yield put({
      type: UPLOADDOCS_FAILED,
      payload: {
        error: true,
      },
    });
  }
```

the issue is that 
`UPLOADDOCS_COMPLETED` being called only after finishing all the api calls.

I want to yield put after every api call how can use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap each call with another generator, and yield it:

```
function *foo(u) {
 yield call(uploadDocs, {...});
 yield put({ type: UPLOADEDDOCS_COMPLETED, .....});
}

yield all(action.uploadDocsBody.map(u => foo(u)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function call(uploadDocs,{...},callback){
  /// do you task
    callback()
}   
function *foo(u) {
  var put  =  function({ type: UPLOADEDDOCS_COMPLETED, .....});   
 yield call(uploadDocs, {...} ,put);

}
```